# Objective-C, call method and wait for nested threads

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I've got a class ("MyClass") which public interface consists of one method and one int field.

Public method ("execute") gets some values from application and launches another private method ("execute:withId:") passing these values as arguments. Private method does some preparing and launches network interaction (uploading files, api interaction) method in a separate thread. Finally API returns int value ("Id") which is put into public int field.

In another class i have method which should do some operation on this Id, like

```
MyClass* c = [Global getMyClassInstance];
[c execute];
int Id = [c getId];
```

Problem is, until all threads created after [c execute] called Id is nil, and i can't find how to wait until all threads are done.

I've tried:

```
        [c performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(execute) withObject:c waitUntilDone:YES];
```

But it doesn't wait. I've also tried dispatch_group with same results. And NSOperationQueue tries to execute selector on NSOperationQueue not an object passed as withObject.

Comment: Since you don't appear to have any control over what `execute:withId:` does internally, trying to synchronize on the public method doesn't seem like a possible solution.  Since the thing you need to know is whether `Id` has changed, is it KVO compatible?  (Or does `MyClass` define a notification?)

Comment: @PhillipMills, i pretty much can change internal implementation of execute:withId anyway i want.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your comment in another answer.  In that case, send some form of notification when you change `Id` and let the class that needs the `Id` value listen for it to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can switch to an async approach (which is better IMO, since you are interacting with networking and APIs), you should make your class use a delegate and invoke the appropriate delegate method when the execution is finished.

Otherwise you should make your `execute` method block until the networking and API interaction is finished: this can be achieved through the `-[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]` method.

Comment: +1 for async. Obvious — [c executeWithCompletion:^(int result){/* */ }]; instead of [c execute]

Comment: Yeah, that would be perfect, but as i mentioned - there is only one public method "execute", which doesn't take any arguments and also part of protocol, used by several other classes. I really don't want to break or change protocol. Is there other way?

Comment: If you cannot change the `MyClass` in any way, then, you should do something nasty like "observing" the public `Id` field for change. You could setup a Category on MyClass adding a method that we can call `[c executeWithCompletion:^(int result){/* */ }];` like @alexander-tkachenko suggests which does this using a timer and blocks the execution until the field has changed.
Kind of a really bad design but it's the cleanest way I see if you cannot change the `MyClass` implementation.

Comment: I've added block reference as member to MyClass and a setter for it. Now i can set callback if needed and MyClass will call it once Id is acquired and protocol is unchanged, though i need a cast to access setter, that's ok. Now i got EXC_BAD_ACCESS problems though, but that's another story. Thanks Alexander, Alessandro.